# Calculation of $\frac{n!}{1!+2!+3!+\cdots+(n-1)!}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Calculation of $\displaystyle \left[\frac{n!}{1!+2!+3!+\cdots+(n-1)!}\right] = $

Where $n\geq 4$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\left[x\right] =$ Greatest Integer of $x$

My Try :: For Upper Bond::

$n! = n.(n-1)! = \{(n-1)+1\}.(n-1)! = (n-1).(n-1)!+(n-1)!$

$ = (n-1).(n-1)!+(n-1).(n-2)!=(n-1).(n-1)!+\{(n-2)+1\}.(n-2)!$

Now I did not understand How can i proceed further.

plz help me , Thanks

Comment: Three dots usually suffice. You get $\cdots$ with `\cdots`.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is $n-2$.

Let the denominator be $D_n$.

**Hint:**  Show that $(n-2) D_n < n! < (n-1) D_n$.

---

For the upper bound,

> Since $n \geq 4$, show that $ (n-1)\left[(n-1)! + (n-2)! + (n-3)!\right] > n! $.

For the lower bound, proceed by induction. Given that $(k-2)D_k < k!$, then

> $(k-1) D_{k+1} = (k-1)D_k + (k-1) k! < \frac{k-1}{k} k! + (k-1) k! < (k+1) k!$

Comment: +1, but how do you think of such beautiful approches.

Comment: Might I ask, why does $(n-2) D_n < n! < (n-1) D_n$ imply the answer is (n-2), doesn't it only bound between the two values? Thank you in advance

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer Do you know what the [Floor Function](https://brilliant.org/wiki/floor-function/) is?

Comment: I understand now. I studied the link, thank you.